# How can I learn which SSD model compatible with my 2010 mid MacBook 13" Unibody (White)?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, ssd

I guess [this one](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/macbook-pro-%2813-inch%2C-mid-2010%29/CT6510172) (Crucial BX100 500GB) is compatible but I need features of it to search for the proper one. Could you guys help me?

Answer (score 1):

All SATA SSDs will work with your MacBook. There is actually no such thing as an SSD only suitable for Mac however a few companies do advertise like this.

So basically any SATA SSD from any brand and with any capacity will work with your MacBook, just make sure that it is a 2.5" internal SSD :)

Before you do actually change to a SSD I recommend you creating either a bootable USB with OS X on it or make sure you've backed up your system via Time Machine on an external hard drive so you can actually install Mac OS on the SSD.

Comment: Not MacBook Pro, MacBook mid 2010 13" Unibody (White). Does it also work for it?

Comment: Macbook Unibody will work perfectly fine too! :)

Comment: Thank you so much. One more question. But this is much more specific. Is it okay for my MacBook: Hi-Level 240 Gb Hlv-ssd30ult/240g S3 550/530 Mb/s

Comment: Should suit your Macbook perfectly :) Your defiantly going to see a lot better performance

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents:  Before replacing your HDD with an SSD (which I've done a couple of times with laptops I've owned), you should upgrade your white Macbook with the latest firmware from Apple for that white 2010 Macbook.
And with the latest firmware installed in your white 2010 Macbook, you can upgrade your RAM to 16GBs and upgrade your HDD/SSD to 2TBs, plus Sierra will run smoother & quicker, too.